# CRM Dynamics 2013 Javascript make a field not updatable

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

Hi I have a scenario where in CRM form onload, I have a function that auto-populates a random generated number. I then open a URL using a Ribbon Button, after that I save the record, My issue when I attempt to save the record the form loads again therefore overrides my random number, which causes data to be corrupt. I have attempted to lock the fiels to readonly after the page loads, but however when the page saves it still ovverrides the value, please see my code below:

```
    function AutonumberGenerator()
     {  
         var uniqueRandoms = [];
         var numRandoms = 500000;

          if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
               for (var i = 0; i < numRandoms; i++) {
               uniqueRandoms.push(i);
           }
      }
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
          var val = uniqueRandoms[index];

         // now remove that value from the array
           uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);


        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_opguploadidentifier").setValue(val); 
           Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_opguploadidentifier").controls.get(0).setDisabled(true);
}
```

Please note I am using CRM Dynamics 2013 ,Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check the value. If it's null, fill it. If it isn't, don't.
Someting like this in your onload, where you now fill the field:

```
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("your_random_number_field").getValue() == null) {
    AutonumberGenerator();
}
```